# how to render an object reappeared on the canvas

Tags: fabricjs

Initially I instantiated a Rect object, by controlling the object's top and left values, making it beyond the canvas area, so that the Rect object will not be rendered on the canvas. After that, change the top and left values of the Rect to make it in the area of the canvas by the event handler and then how to render the Rect object on the canvas.

the following code is a demo:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
<script src="js/fabric.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
        fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

        var targetLine = [], paramsG, paramsR;

        for (var k = 0; k < 20; k++) {
            paramsG = {
                left: 200,
                top: 530 - 100 * k,
                width: 20,
                height: 50,
                visibile: false,
                fill: '#62ab59',
                hasBorders: false,
                lockMovementX: true,
                hasControls: false
            };
            paramsR = {
                left: 200,
                top: 580 - 100 * k,
                width: 20,
                height: 50,
                visibile: false,
                fill: '#ed5d5d',
                hasBorders: false,
                lockMovementX: true,
                hasControls: false
            };
            canvas.add(new fabric.Rect(paramsG), new fabric.Rect(paramsR));
        }


        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
            if (e.target) {
                targetLine = getMemberByLeft(canvas._objects, e.target);
            }
        })

        canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) {
            targetLine.forEach(function (val) {
                canvas._objects[val.index].set({top: e.e.movementY + canvas._objects[val.index].top});
            })
            canvas.renderAll();
        })

        function getMemberByLeft(arr, tar) {
            var returnArr = [];
            arr.forEach(function (value, key) {
                if (value.left == tar.left && value != tar) {
                    returnArr.push({data: value, index: key});
                }
            })
            return returnArr;
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide the code what you tried @volcano.y

Answer (score 0):

Fabric has a function to skip object rendering if they are not visible on screen, to get some more speed.

If you change top and left by code, fabric will not understand that the object is again on screen unless you call `object.setCoords()`

If you do not want to have this behaviour automatic you can disable it using

```
canvas.skipOffscreen = false;
```

Comment: Thank you for disabusing. In the above demo I encountered another question, after I moved a rect and released the mouse,  to move others rects, I found that some can not move, the cursor value of which changed became the default value.

Comment: the above demo is not running in a stack overflow snippet, is hard to understand what is going on